# Custom loss based on input data for Keras linear regression model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a large number of grey scale images containing text, and I need to create a mask of the text in each image. These images look something like this.

[image]

If you apply a threshold to this image using `cv2.inRange`, it creates a binary mask of the image, like this.

[image]

The problem is that, the values for the threshold are different for each image, and some images require multiple thresholds to be added together to create an accurate mask.

I have tried training an AI using Keras to create the mask by itself, however, that was often inaccurate, and using thresholds generally returns something that is quite close to the target image.

Instead of training an AI to create a mask, I want to train an AI to find the values for the threshold(s). I want to use the difference between the input image with the predicted threshold applied and the target mask as the 'score' for each prediction.

The function to find the score for a prediction might look something like this:

```py
def get_score(input_image, target_image, prediction):
    ## Some input images may require multiple 'thresholdings'
    mask = cv2.inRange(input_image, prediction[0], prediction[1])
    mask_include = cv2.inRange(input_image, prediction[2], prediction[3])
    mask_exclude = cv2.inRange(input_image, prediction[4], prediction[5])

    ## Combine the 'thresholded' images
    mask[(mask_include == 255) | (mask == 255)] = 1
    mask[mask_exclude == 255] = 0

    ## Return accuracy as a number between 1 and 0
    return np.sum(np.abs(target_image-mask))/target_image.size
```

I tried to make a simplified version of this using Keras tensor instead of NumPy, however, no matter what I tried I got an error along the lines of `You are passing KerasTensor([...])`.

```py
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
    mask = K.cast(K.greater(inputs, y_pred[1]) & K.less(inputs, y_pred[0]), 'int8')
    mask = K.cast(K.equal(K.cast(K.reshape(y_true[..., 1], (-1, 48, 128, 1)), 'int8'), mask), 'int8')
    mask = K.mean(K.sum(K.reshape(mask, (-1, 1, 6144)), axis=-1), axis=-1)
    return mask


inputs = keras.Input(shape=(img_size[1], img_size[0], 1,))

model = keras.Sequential([
    inputs,
    keras.layers.Conv2D(3, 3, activation='relu'),
    ## Majority of layers removed for readability
    keras.layers.Dense(units=2)
])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.005), loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I want to have a linear regression model that takes an image as the input and target but outputs a series of numbers (2 to 6 long). To train the AI, I want to use the prediction of the model plus the input and target images to calculate the 'score' of each prediction. Is this possible in Keras or TensorFlow, and if so, what do I need to change in the code above to make this work?